# dimension of $P_n(\mathbb{Z}_3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

$P_n(F)$ is the vector space of polynomial functions $f : F \rightarrow F$ with degree $f \leq n$. I'm asked to find dim$P_n(\mathbb{Z}_3)$.

First, I know dim($P_n$) is $n+1$ because there is the obvious basis $\{1, x, x^2 \cdots, x^n\}$. However, why, and how, would the coefficients being elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ change the overall dimension?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by $\mathbb Z_3$ you mean the field with three elements (and not the [3-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#p-adic_integers)).

It doesn't have any impact on the dimension. It's still a basis (over $\mathbb Z_3$).

The only thing that changes is the base field. Namely, for any field $k$, the set of polynomials of degree at most $n$ has dimension $n$ *over $k$* (this is easily checked directly using the definition).

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by $n$ over $k$ numerically? Like $\frac{n}{k}$?

Comment: No, I mean dimenson $n$ over the field $k$. $k$ is a field here, not a number.